# how to erase lines with wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, gdi

I'm trying to make a paint tool in wxpython. and i couldn't find a way to make an ( Eraser ) . how can i make an eraser tool - just like the one in windows paint - in wxpython ?
please help .
the idea or small code sample would be very helpful

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you made a Pen tool? Just set its colour to the canvas' background colour  ;)

by the way I actively develop my own wxpython painting program that you may want to check out; see http://code.google.com/p/whyteboard/

Comment: +1 AWESOME WORK ! .. what im trying  to do the nearly the same as the software you have . except for  its only to draw comments given by directors . ( it's specific for 2D animation). and i have to admit, i got really disappointed  from my self after seeing your work !. thanks

Comment: but what if i have the background as an image . i dont want to  erase any part of that image. i just want to erase lines above it. any ideas?

Comment: How have you programmed the pen/eraser? Like in the "Doodle" wxPython demo (a list of (x, y) points)? I'm struggling to think how to not erase the image, sorry :(